# C++ Data-Url as String to const byte *

Tags: c++, string, byte

I have a [Data-Url](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-URL) of a file as std:string.
The base64 encoded data has to be decoded and then be passed to this function:

```
open (const byte *  data, long size)
```

So first i extract the encoded data

```
size_t pos = dataurl.find_first_of(',');
std::string encoded = dataurl.substr(spos + 1);
```

Then i use this [base64 decoder](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html)

```
std::string decoded = base64_decode(encoded);
```

Well, how can i cast 'decoded' of type string to byte*?
The following code produces an error

```
open((byte *)decoded.c_str(), decoded.size() + 1);
//>>error: 'byte' was not declared in this scope
```

/EDIT: so there is a typedef

```
typedef uint8_t     byte
```

the encoded data is an image!

Comment: Make sure you include the header that defines `byte` and use the [`decoded.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

Comment: Where is the open function declared?  Is it a member of a class?  part of a namespace?

Comment: And if there isn't one, heck! it's probably a typedef for `unsigned char`.

Comment: typedef uint8_t     byte

Comment: You seem to be missing an include to a header file. More specifically the header file where `byte` is typedef'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are removing `const`.  `c_str()` returns a `const char *`.  Your cast should be `(const byte *)`.

Comment: You should use data() instead of c_str(), since you just want to access the binary representation of the std::string, not a version with an added \0 byte. It could be, that c_str() is more costly, than data().

Answer (score -1):

byte is an unsigned char. try `open((unsigned char *)decoded.c_str(), decoded.size() + 1);`

and yes, depending on what was encoded in the original base64 string, you might want to use a different approach to decoding